# Android referral tracking does not work

Tags: android, google-analytics, referrer

I am attempting to get Android Referral tracking to work. I am following the only documentation I have found here http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#referrals  I have the following in my android manifest file

```
<receiver  
android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"  
android:exported="true">  
    <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>  
<receiver android:name="com.package.Receiver" android:exported="true">  
        <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

com.package.Receiver starts with:

```
public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {  
        String str1 = paramIntent.getStringExtra("referrer");  
        Log.i("myapp", "action: '" + paramIntent.getAction() + "'  
referrer string: '" + str1 + "'");
```

Also with a little bit of decompiling com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver has the following code in it:

```
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)  
/*     */   {  
/*  24 */     String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");  
/*     */  
/*  26 */     if ((!  
("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER".equals(intent.getAction())))  
|| (referrer == null))  
/*     */     {  
/*  28 */       return;  
/*     */     }  
/*     */ 
/*  31 */     String formattedReferrer = formatReferrer(referrer);  
/*     */  
/*  33 */     if (formattedReferrer != null) {  
/*  34 */       PersistentEventStore store = new  
PersistentEventStore(ctx);  
/*  35 */       store.setReferrer(formattedReferrer);  
/*  36 */       Log.d("googleanalytics", new  
StringBuilder().append("Stored   
referrer:").append(formattedReferrer).toString());  
/*     */     } else {  
/*  38 */       Log.w("googleanalytics", "Badly formatted referrer, ignored");  
/*     */     }  
/*     */   }
```

Note the two lines 36 and 38 that Log "googleanalytics" I have tried pushing the above app to the market, downloading it on my Nexus One (after uninstalling a previous version of the app). I have generated a link using the google page I linked to at the beginning of this post

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://market.android.com/search%3Fq%3Dpname:com.package.app%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_term%253Drunning%25252Bshoes%2526utm_content%253Dcontent1%2526utm_campaign%253Dslogan&usg=AFQjCNFctwqk1WgWl0bhiIBNVqy3U4OPRw`

I attached logcat to my Nexus One while I download the app from that link, I do not see any logs from "googleanalytics" or "myapp". The rest of the google analytics library does work for my app. I.E. I see records on google analytics about pages hits etc. However all the traffic sources are "Direct Traffic". I am at a loss as to what is going on. Does anyone 
have any insight into what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Highlight your code and hit the {} box to display it correctly, don't put it in quotes.

Comment: It looks like you or someone else already did it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, you **can not** have multiple Broadcast receivers receiving the same event. If you want to do this, you must create one receiver, which will pass it to all others

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As is often the case I found my own answer. My problem was in my AndroidManifest.xml

I had the following in my manifest:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
    </application>
    <receiver>
    </receiver>
    <uses-sd/>
 </manifest>
```

The receiver tag was in the wrong spot. It should look like this

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <receiver>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sd/>
 </manifest>
```

I am now seeing the logs I expect to when I install the app. In a few hours hopefully Google Analytics will have the data as well.

Answer (score 9):

I have explore quite a lot the referral tracker with analytics for android. You don't need to put the app in the market you can just send a broadcast intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
i.setPackage(com.package.yourapp)
//referrer is a composition of the parameter of the campaing
i.putExtra("referrer", referrer);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one BroadcastReceiver for an action. In your AndroidManifest.xml, you have two listening for `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`.

If you want to your receiver AND the Google Analytics receiver to both handle the intent, make your receiver a subclass of AnalyticsReceiver, like this:

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver;

class Receiver extends AnalyticsReceiver {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        // Add your custom handling here
    }
}
```

Then make sure yours is the only receiver in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.Receiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Can you tell me more about Analytics Receiver? I can't find the class anywhere.