# Android Market Referrer Data Not Being Populated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-play, referrer

I've implemented a BroadcastReceiver to receive and parse Android Market referrer data. I followed the steps here: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking and this all works fine and dandy when I navigate to the referring link on my actual device, but when I navigate to the same referral link and choose to send the app to my device the referral data does not get sent.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Is the market referral data only available when accessing the referral link on the actual device? Seems like I might be missing something...

---

EDIT: In case someone was wondering, I've found it not possible to retrieve referrer data this way. Installing an app using the market app on your phone is the only way the INSTALL_REFERRER intent action will be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing an app using the market app on your device is the only way the referrer parameter will be passed and the INSTALL_REFERRER intent action will be thrown. Does not get passed if sending app from computer to mobile device.

Comment: True. BTW for testing purposes, you can simulate a market install using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking/6966718#6966718

Comment: i have tried the link of testing purpose and it works but as i download app it show null value