# How could I implement referral program for app users in Android market?

Tags: android, google-play

I want provide bonuses to users how have shared link to my android application. How could I implement referral program for app users in Android market?

Currently I don't understand how to determine source who provided reference of android market link to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Android Market Campaign Tracking documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#android-market-tracking

It's pretty easy to generate a unique "campaign content" per user, and substitute that into the market url. That would get provided to your broadcast receiver and processed by you as you wish.

Comment: Yep, This works. However it doesn't see the referrer if user installed app from market website. Or may by Im doing something wrong?

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov have found any thing for referrer i have manually checked as on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking/6966718#6966718 accepted ans and it give output but if i update my app in market and try to get referre it return nothing if u know than inform me

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov you can use the 'utm-source' parameter in the url for this purpose. According to http://gyurigrell.com/2012/02/tracking-install-sources-for-android-apps/ , Use utm_source to identify a search engine, newsletter name, or other source. Use the URl builder for better understanding https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en