# In Android, do we really need Branch?

Tags: android, deep-linking, referrals, branch.io

Isn't Branch really redundant, at least in Android? With questions like: [Android - Is it possible to get install referrer programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103338/android-is-it-possible-to-get-install-referrer-programatically)
where we can do our own deep-linking, isn't Branch just another redundant tool now(at least in android)?
I can do all the things that Branch offers without integrating Branch at all.
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Full disclosure: I did a Branch app integration last year and now work with the Branch team.)*

This is a good question, and you're right: the deep linking landscape on Android has advanced quite significantly, especially with the introduction of App Links in Android M. As you mentioned, the [Google Play Install Referrer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver#public-constructor-summary) (which Branch does also use) is available to anyone and passes a limited amount of data through the installation process. However it doesn't *always* get delivered reliably and isn't especially flexible. Many of Branch's partners had previously tried this approach and found it was too slow.

### Branch does still offer a few benefits

Since there aren't really any deep linking 'standards' yet, Branch can still be a useful plug-and-play option for developers. Here are a few specific areas where Branch helps:

#### Edge cases

Given how many Android devices and OS versions are available, there are a ton of these. You’ll think everything is going great until you get that one user complaining that her links aren’t working on Facebook while running Android 4.4.4. Branch is currently tracking over 6000 of these situations ([source](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-deep-link-from-your-mobile-website)), which can save you this nightmare and ensure that your links work everywhere.

#### Data flexibility

The Google Play Install Referrer lets you pass in a few strings via URL query parameters, but it isn't persistent storage and only works during the first install. Branch allows you to send almost anything you can think of (and also [adds some useful analytics data](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#branch-provided-data-parameters-in-callback)), and it's available permanently with every link your users ever click.

#### Cross-platform

I know you asked specifically about Android, but if your app has an iOS version (or might launch one in future) then Branch makes it really easy to handle everything with a single system.

#### Value-added tools

Not deep link tech per se, but Branch can also let your users [preview app content before installing](https://branch.io/features/#deepviews), [text themselves download links from their computer](https://branch.io/features/#text-me-the-app), and see **[detailed analytics for every piece of content inside the app](https://branch.io/features/#content-analytics)**, amongst others. Yes, of course those could all be developed in-house, but they're a big resource commitment.

Comment: This is a pretty fine explanation. Thanks for the descriptive answer. I'm shifting towards using Branch for my deep-linking now. :)

Comment: That would be awesome! Please let me know once you've had a chance to give it a try — would love to hear any thoughts you might have

Comment: Also, if you don't mind accepting the answer, that might help anyone else with the same question in future! :)