# Check how many people installed android app with my invitation link

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am a newbie to the android, I would like to know if there is an option to know how many people installed my app via others invitation.

What I mean is that lets say I installed the app and send some URL to my friend to download this app also.

Now after he/she download this app he/she send an URL for their friends , and i would like to know how many friends of mine installed this app.

Is it possible to do it via code?

Comment: You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30255200/5343320)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without writing any code. Just share your build through Beta by Fabric.

You can setup Fabric for your project manually or automatically(through a plugin):
https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html

This is instructions on how to distribute builds:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/beta-walkthrough.html

To get a link to the build:

1. Go to Fabric dashboard.
2. Choose your app.
3. Click Beta(on left panel).
4. Click Share links.
5. Generate link.

After each installation through the link(by your friends) you will get an email. Also, you will get a daily summary of installs. 
And you can find statistics about new installs on Fabric dashboard.

Comment: Thanks , but i need this data in my app so i would like to get it with code

Comment: @MichaelReznik You didn't specify in your question that you would like to have this data inside your app. In this case, the best solution would be to have this data on the server(e. g. Firebase). Firebase registers every user through anonymous auth. Try to get this data.