# How to get information from google play app link?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I share my app link to my friend with invitation id.

This is the link of my app in google play with invitation id that i shared with my friend

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manticsol.coucou.pk&inviteid=4352627

Now my friend install the app using my link that i shared with him. Can anyone tell me how can i get the invitation id programmatically in my app when my friend will install app using my link

I know that this intent is called when app installed first time from play store but i don't know how can i able to get the inviteId

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I got a little bit help from this link

[Android - Is it possible to get install referrer programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103338/android-is-it-possible-to-get-install-referrer-programmatically)

But when i implemented this thing in my app. i am getting this response in logcat

**utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Is it possible to get install referrer programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103338/android-is-it-possible-to-get-install-referrer-programmatically)

Comment: hi Mikhail i implemented same thing but i am not able to get information.

Comment: when i implemented then i got this response
utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set) 
can you help me to solve my issue please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use any old string you want - in this case `inviteid`.
You have to use a `referrer` argument, then you can put other sub arguments inside it like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foo.bar&referrer=utm_source%3Dmyreferrer%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_term%3Dshoes%26utm_content%3Dfoo%26utm_campaign%3Dcampaign

Various online tools [like this one](https://www.digitangle.co.uk/toolsandresources/google-play-url-builder/) help you build the URL correctly.