# Android: How to get parameter from install link

Tags: android, installation, url-parameters

I'm a new in Android, so I don't know if it is possible.

Let's say I sent to user an install link to my application, something like *www.mysite.com/files/myapp.apk?email=user.email@gmail.com*

Do I have a way to get parameter **email** from this link in my application when it will be installed in user telephone? For example, in my launch activity.

**EDITED:**
I tried this code in my main activity, but it returns NULL always:

```
getIntent().getDataString()
```

Comment: Please refer this for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103338/android-is-it-possible-to-get-install-referrer-programmatically

Comment: I don't use Google Play Store

Comment: You can just make the check that link `contains` **email** or not and then use the `subString` method to get the **string** which you want

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha It's my problem - how do I need to do it? See my edited answer.