# Can a unique code parameter be added to an app link so that user doesn't have to enter it

Tags: android

I have a link to an app that requires a code (unique to us) be entered by the person downloading it.  Is there a way for us to create a link that include our unique code?  The link is:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.go_agent_mobile&hl=en

The unique code that I would like to add is: Just a few Letters and Numbers that signify what realtor is assigned.

I haven't tried anything out as I have never used URL parameters and don't totally understand the process.  Not even sure if my question is valid and doable.  I will also want to do the same for the apple app. If this is even doable.  Thank you.

Comment: I think dynamic links can do what you want, you could read up on them here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this shortly.

Comment: you can achieve this via Install Referral

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103338/android-is-it-possible-to-get-install-referrer-programmatically] you can find here how to do this

Comment: Oh, wow, I just looked through the question 30103338/ thread. I realize that this is way beyond my skill. This was just the first of many changes that we are making to our "marketing program" (one realtor and me) :). Salman Aziz. Are you a website or coding developer? I am not sure what to ask even.  I think that I am looking for someone to help fix up integration/automate of our few facebook ads and also our webpage. Hopefully this is ok to ask here.

Comment: Oh, wow, I just looked through the question 30103338/ thread. I realize that this is way beyond my skill. This was just the first of many changes that we are making to our "marketing program" (one realtor and me) :). @SalmanAziz. Are you a website or coding developer? I am not sure what to ask even. I think that I am looking for someone to help fix up integration/automate of our few facebook ads and also our webpage. Hopefully this is ok to ask here. – geddeca 13 mins ago

Comment: @geddeca i am android developer with expertise in java and kotlin