# Android Referal System withing my app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to make an app which will pay users money on downloading another apps from within my app, so how can i track that user had downloaded that app or not, and i want to make sure that after user registered in the downloaded app then only he/she is going to get money, so how can i do this.
Some examples of these types of apps are : Ladooo app, TaskBucks App, Pokkt App,

I found following links which helped me somehow but it is not clear :

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/12/analytics-for-android-apps.html

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the list of installed applications in the following manner

```
// retrieve the list of installed applications
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = mPm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

can get the package name of the app through

```
String pkg = apps.get(i).packageName;
```

I know this is not the full answer but i hope this helps

Comment: thanks @raktale, but i am able to get list of apps but i want to track those apps from within my app, that user had downloaded that app or not from play store

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure About your requirement or not have idea about playstore api but can give simple logic for this, hope it will help.

When any user share or refer the application for download to other user, create one unique id from the serverside(combination with user who refer) in simple word redirect url to playstore with uniqueid and share that link with intent.

When user register you can check or if redirect url for playstore is via your server than you can send money or points when redirect link callback on server.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22246314/3514144)
or you can refer some codes on github:
[here](https://github.com/appvirality/appvirality-sdk-android/wiki/Android-SDK-Integration-Steps-for-Personalized-Referrals-GrowthHack) or [here](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-InstallReferrer)