# How could I implement referral program for app users in ios market?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I want to implement the referral program in my iOS app, like if an user refer the link to some of his friend to download my app and that user download the app from app store my clicking on that link, it will give some bonus to the user which refer the link.

Comment: You can use Firebase Invites. https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios, https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Short Google search and you already get tons of hits:

Great tool is Branch.io: https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/guide/ios/

But there are also other resources/tools out there like:

- AppVirality: https://github.com/appvirality/AppVirality-iOS-SDK
- Viraltrics: http://viraltrics.com/

If you are looking to do it on your own, you'll find a great concept here: [How to implement referral program in mobile Apps for both Android and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006674/how-to-implement-referral-program-in-mobile-apps-for-both-android-and-iphone)