# How to Post Data to Android App using Inbound Connection?

Tags: android

Is it possible to post data directly to an Android app from some URL on a local network using inbound connection?

Example: My Android device(Device 1) is running on local IP: xxx.xxx.x.146 and another Non-Android device(Device 2) is running on local IP: xxx.xxx.x.147. Device 2 only post data to URL. My requirement is to share Device 1 URL with Device 2, so that Device 2 can post data directly to Device 1 over same network. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Gaurav Kapoor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a HTTP server in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/how-to-create-a-http-server-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to go with below way then it should be possible but rest cases not feasible please check below if it will help to you.

Option:1 with help firebase dynamic link to give data from url.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

Option:2 using some referral way for more details check below link

[How to get Google Play referer in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895757/how-to-get-google-play-referer-in-an-android-application)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know If this solution will work or not.

Comment: Added example what I want to achieve. Also the app is not on Play Store, It's an enterprise application.