# Retrieving all Campaign Parameter appended to GooglePlay URL

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I found this script to test Google Campaign Parameters received:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.accuweather.android/com.accuweather.android.services.GoogleCampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_androidlite_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966718/371778)

Here is how I am receiving it for testing purposes:

```
public class GoogleCampaignTrackingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");

        Logger.i(this, "referrer string is %s", referrerString);
}
}
```

And I am wondering how I get all the parameters, not just the first?  Here is the log statement:

```
03-13 18:40:41.990: I/GoogleCampaignTrackingReceiver(30212): referrer string is utm_source=test_androidlite_source
```

Comment: I have the same problem :( have you been able to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm faced same issue and spend couple hours to find the answer.
In my case, i send broadcast

> ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER --es
>   "referrer"
>   "traffic=test1&md=1t1&utm_source=test1&utm_medium=android&utm_campaign=test12&utm_term=t3&utm_content=t5

And got only first param

Solution is simple - you need enter the adb shell first

> ./adb shell

And then send your broadcast

> shell@android:/ $  am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER --es
>   "referrer"
>   "traffic=test1&md=1t1&utm_source=test1&utm_medium=android&utm_campaign=test12&utm_term=t3&utm_content=t5

All params will be received correctly.
I hope it will be useful, since i have not find such explanations