# Google Analytics V2 (GAV2) Easy Tracker sendView not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to set dynamically the name of an activity. However this is not working correctly, once I am watching it in real time and (even if I wait for a while) only the name of the main activity is shown and not of other activities.

I have already tried several approaches, (used in all activities) e.g.:

- Using EasyTracker with activityStart(this) and sendView("title")
- Using GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker('xxx').sendView("title")

However, none seems to work and I only see the first activity title in GA's website.

Besides, the documentation is not quite exaustive if you wish not to use EasyTracker, so maybe I am not doing any sort of flush, etc.

With the debugger on, sometimes I see some already existing errors (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581347/google-analytics-for-android-v2-campaign-tracking-not-working) or others, but they don't seem to be causing the error, once there are several 'Sending hit to store').

Comment: There is already a new version of Google Analytics that comes with the Google Play Services, which is working nicely.