# Facebook Mobile app install ad tracking (without SDK)

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, tracking

What are the alternative ways for us to track downloads without installing the FB Android SDK (we prefer not using SDKs due to various reasons)? Ideally, we want to route the click to our tracking server prior to sending the user to the Play Store, but could settle with adding a referrer without routing the user to our tracking server. If the latter is an option, where in the setup do we specify the referrer value?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you could also use the **Google Analytics SDK** to capture the Intent containing referral data.

Essentially you'd create a **BroadcastReceiver (AnalyticsReceiver/CampaignTrackingReceiver)** that listens for the installation event and passes and Intent with referral data after install to the app.

Valuable information regarding this method can be seen in the links below:

[How to test android referral tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?hl=en