# Android install referral isn't working on kitkat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, install-referrer

Install referral isn't working on KitKat devices but it works on previous versions of Android. Has anyone come across the same problem?

Comment: How did you confirm that it is not working? Did this test work?- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966718/713778

Comment: I have nailed it anyways thanks for your -1. Yes I have tested it and it works from shell but when the user downloads the app by clicking a link from kitkat device it takes them to browser and not to playstore app, as these referral things only work if the user installs from playstor. so it was not working.

Comment: Oops I did not realize the -1. Must have been an accident.