# Emulate a play store app download on android emulator for a local apk

Tags: android, emulation, affiliate

I'm working on an app with affiliate referral.

A referral can be sent in the URL like so:

> play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**< MY APP >**&referrer=**< AFFILIATE NAME >**

I'm willing to read the **referrer** parameter, but in order to do that, the app needs to be downloaded from play store.

**I don't want to upload my app to the store yet, it's a long process for just debugging.**

Therefore I'm asking if there's a way to emulate a play sore download for a local apk.

*** EDIT ***

I found a way to track my referral here: [How to test android referral tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking)

Despite that, my question stands still.