# How to setUp google analytics campaign measurements ? android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to setUp google analytics campaign measurements [measurements](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) .

here is what i did :

1.
i've declared the receiver in the manifest file:

```
<!-- Enable Google Play Store Campaign reports -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

2. I install the app on my device using this command:

   ./adb install debug.apk
3. then i run this using my terminal , to broadcast the intent :

   ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "com.mypackgename/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "utm_source=test2Source&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"

which return this :

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.mypackagename/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

but i got this in my log:

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

what should i do to make it work, i'v try a lot of things but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to URL encode the arguments in the referrer string.

Please try the following:

> ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "com.mypackgename/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "utm_source%3Dtest2Source%26utm_medium%3DtestMedium%26utm_term%3DtestTerm%26utm_content%3DtestContent%26utm_campaign%3DtestCampaign"

For more information check out: [How to test android referral tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking/6966718#6966718)